# SQL auto_increment non-int-only values

Tags: mysql

I was looking into auto_increment and I would like to automatically generate unique id primary key. The problem is I only know how to do that with numerical ids. As far as I know, primary keys have to be unique. So I cant use numerical auto_increment for multiple tables because the id wont be unique. Here's how I do it now:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
id int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name char(20),
lastname char(20)
);
```

To the best of my knowledge this will generate ids like: 1, 2, 3, 4 unless I name a different starting number. Would it be possible to autoi_increment something like "stud_1" or "stud_01" and then keep going increasing the number? I haven't come across such an example so far.

Comment: numerical `auto_increment` has to be unique within the same table, not across all tables. When you talk about cross table values you get into the realm of foreign key constraints, which (for the purposes of this question) can be thought of as a lookup from whatever table you're linking too. It's the job of the table being linked to though to enforce that the primary key is unique. The table being linked from must only validate that the value is in the linked to table. ***TLDR:*** you're safe to use numerical `auto_increment` in multiple tables.

Comment: i want it to be primary key. primary keys have to be unique through the whole database, dont they?

Comment: Per table, yes. Think of the data being structured like this: DATABASE Name > Table Name > ID (numerical primary key). You'll never have that same combo within the same database. You could also represent this like so: `dbname.students.id` is unique across the database. But so would `dbname.subjects.id` for instance. Both would be numerical `auto_increment` keys but both are unique in that db instance.

Comment: oh.. i think i must have mixed up the fact that primary key COLUMN names have to be unique and thought that values have to be too or something then probably?

Comment: seing the edited reply i think i was wrong again. though im pretty sure thats what my teacher said :/

Comment: @NulisDefo No, primary key column names don't have to be unique across the database. You can have lots of tables that all have an primary key called `id`.

Comment: The only thing that has to be unique across the database is foreign key names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a lot in the comments above, but let me apply it to a pratical application in an answer. We'll begin with your table and then add two more:

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    id int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name char(20),
    lastname char(20)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE subjects (
    id int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name char(20)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE student_subject (
    student_id int(3) NOT NULL,
    subject_id int(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(student_id, subject_id)
    FOREIGN KEY(student_id) references students(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(subject_id) references subjects(id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

With a setup of tables like this, it is possible to have multiple numerical `auto_increment` primary key columns within the same database. In this case, there are two `students.id` and `subjects.id`. The third table `student_subject` shows how to link these together where both `student_id` and `subject_id` are primary keys for that table but each is a foreign key of their entity table as well.

With a setup like this querying becomes simple:

**Sample Queries:**

```
/* Get All students */
SELECT
students.id,
students.name,
students.lastname
FROM students;

/* Get All Subjects */
SELECT
subjects.id,
subjects.name
FROM subjects;

/* Get all subjects for a particular student */
SELECT
subjects.name
FROM subjects
INNER JOIN student_subject ON subjects.id = student_subject.subject_id
INNER JOIN students ON student_subject.student_id = students.id
WHERE students.id = 1;
```

**EDIT:**

Below is some sample data that demonstrates the three table many-to-many concept that the above structure illustrates:

```
/* Students Table */
+----+----------------+----------------+
| id | name           | lastname       |
+----+----------------+----------------+
|  1 | John           | Doe            |
|----|----------------|----------------|
|  2 | Joe            | Bob            |
+----+----------------+----------------+

/* Subjects Table */
+----+----------------+
| id | name           |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | Calculus       |
|----|----------------|
|  2 | Physics        |
|----|----------------|
|  3 | Geography      |
+----+----------------+

/* Student Subject Table */
+------------+------------+
| student_id | subject_id |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |          1 |
|------------|------------|
|          1 |          2 |
|------------|------------|
|          2 |          2 |
|------------|------------|
|          2 |          3 |
+------------+------------+
```

With this table structure, each student can have many subjects and each subject can belong to many students. For example, John Doe (student 1) is enrolled in both Calculus (subject 1) and Physics (subject 2). Joe Bob (student 2) is enrolled in Geography (subject 3) and also in Physics (subject 2) with John Doe.

In this example, each student is enrolled in two subjects and both students are enrolled in one subject. With the example you linked to from *w3schools.com*, this many-to-many relationship would not be possible.

Comment: so here you create a separate table for linking the two tables. if instead of creating the third table i would put foreign keys in first two tables everything would work the same? (something like whats shown at the beggining here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Comment: So the example you posted is a 1-1 (one to one) relationship between the tables. For ordering that makes sense. Once unique order number belongs to one unique customer. In the example above, I used a third table to allow for many-to-many relationships. In this case one student can have many subjects that they're enrolled in and one subject can have many students enrolled in it.

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify if i understand correctly. The relations in the third table are defined manually by your hand. That's correct, right?

Comment: I think? I'm not quite sure exactly what you mean but I'm leaning toward yes. Let me update the answer with some data.

Comment: what i meant is that in the third table u input (as in this case) which student is taking which classes (or what students attend what classes). i mean that i dont miss something that autodefines that so it would go something like `insert into student_subject values (null, 1, 1);` which means student with id=1 is taking class with id=1

Comment: @NulisDefo In that case, yes that's correct. I've updated the answer with some data to support this and demo what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key values only need to be unique within a table, so there's no reason you can't use simple auto-increment numeric ids for every table.

As far as the question - I don't believe there's a direct way to "auto-increment" a string value in the way you describe.  You could set something up with triggers and a sequence (or regular auto-increment column) if you really wanted to.